# Read PDF checkboxes with python to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, pypdf

We have done a questionnaire with over 16 pages.
We used PDF formulas with checkboxes for this matter.
Now I want to extract the checkbox information with python to put the data within pandas.

I tried:

```
pdfFileObj = open(PDF_Path, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
checkboxes = pdfReader.getFields(tree=None, retval=None, fileobj=None)
df_checkboxes_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(checkboxes)
df_checkboxes_data
```

But the data seems to not contain the information if the boxes are checked or not...

Is there a way to get the information, if the checkboxes are active/checked or not?

Comment: PyPDF2>=2.0.0 has [adjusted its naming patterns](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/migration-1-to-2.html#naming-adjustments), so `PdfFileReader` is now `PdfReader` and `getFields` is now `get_fields`.

Comment: If you are open to other packages, you may want to try [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/),which lets you easily do this type of thing.

Comment: Please also note that development on `PyPDF2` has stopped, but is being continued in `PyPDF` (no 2 at the end), probably because it is now version 3. `PyPDF` is currently at version 3.6.0, while `PyPDF2` is only at 3.0.1.

Comment: Im checking the ideas and will give a feedback soon, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @MattDMo `pypdf` is all-lowercase. Everywhere. That is one of the confusions I hoped to remove with the switch. The "2" in the end was "removed" because people got confused about it. Now it's all lowercase without a number. It was just a coincidence that we had version 3.x as well. Development will continue with `pypdf`

Comment: @MartinThoma good to know, thanks for chiming in